# CO2 probe measuring at temperatures up to 150 °C

Tags: co2, carbon-cycle

I'm looking for a $CO_2$ measuring probe (analog current output, digital out: RS232/485 - probe will be connected and transferring real time data to the data logger) that would operate up to 150 °C (hot air sucked out from the heated column which is highly concentrated by $CO_2$).

Another $CO_2$ probe should measure (rather control) trace amount of $CO_2$ after it's separated from the exhaust gas (small scale experimental boiler burning coal) - operating temp. approx. 75 °C.

I have found tons of probes, but all of them measure up to + 60/65 °C.

Do you have any experiences with such probes?

Comment: I am not an expert, but a quick google by including "high temp" gave me some solutions
https://www.vaisala.com/en/products/instruments-sensors-and-other-measurement-devices/instruments-industrial-measurements/gmp231

Comment: this question is a better fit over at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: or engineering.

Comment: @trondhansen I see, I was having hard time finding a proper StackExchange community, thanks.

Comment: @EarlGrey I came by many similar types of probes. There's a difference between conditions the probe can withstand and the operating conditions. Probes for incubators are designed for sterilization cycles which are up to 200 °C because it won't make much sense to remove them every time. As for this one, it can measure $CO_2$ up to +70 °C. My case is to measure at higher temp.

Comment: ok, got it, then you will have better luck with remote sensing, volcanology may help you, try to google "remote sensing co2 volcano".

Comment: @EarlGrey thanks. Installing such measuring may "do the job". Unfortunately, I think it's not possible to install such devices into a gas tube. From what I've found, these measurements are rather specific and require special instrumentation.